# cumulative moving average optimisation

Tags: numerics, probability-or-statistics

I'm trying to optimise my cumulative moving average calculation code, I originally just compute the `dynamic summation / count` but it is not efficient when the data becomes massive. I understand the optimised logic, but I have a bit of trouble to implement it, much appreciated if can use some help, the logic is the following

```
data1n2 = (data[[1]]+data[[2]])/ 2

data1n2n3 = (data1n2 * 2 + data[[3]]) / 3

data1n2n3n4 = (data1n2n3 * 3 + data[[4]]) /4
                  .
                  .
                  .
```

I know for a data file with `{170,1}` seems pointless to optimise the code, this is just an example, my actual input file contains 30 million data points, so I figured optimise this will significantly reduce the cpu hour.
Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How fast do you need it to be?  Here's an example with 30 million data points:

```
n = 30000000;
x = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], n];
Timing[ma = Accumulate[x]/Range[1, n];]
(* {14.9604959`,Null} *)
```

Comment: Hey @Jim , thanks for introducing me `Accumulative` function, I didn't know such thing exists in Mathematica, although I can't really tell the difference between it and my original code, here's my code:

           `sum = Table[Sum[data[[i]], {i, 1, j}]/j, {j, 1, Length[data]}]`

and my input file has Dimension `{30000000,1}` it's been running for 18hours already, any idea why would it make such difference?

Comment: Think about what is calculated in each step of `Table`

Comment: @Sascha each step of `Table` is calculating `current sum/count`, and I checked `Accumulative` in Mathematica guide, it seems it's doing the same thing?

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf No; `Accumulate` does the sum once; `Table` is doing it 30,000,000 times.

Comment: I see, just did a comparison of my method vs. `Accumulate`, it comes out the latter one is 25 times faster for 170 data points, I'd like to think this ratio follows an exponentially increasing curve as the number of data points increase...thanks all!

Comment: @GavyLittlewolf By the way if `Accumulate` did not exist the best way to implement it in top-level *Mathematica* code is to use `FoldList`, i.e. `FoldList[Plus, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]`.  See case #3 in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121 for another example.

Comment: "I'd like to think this ratio follows an exponentially increasing curve" - more like you're doing $O(n^2)$ effort for a problem that can be done with $O(n)$ effort, as `Accumulate[]`/`FoldList[]` does.